# How to remove duplicate values in one column and concatenate values from another column where removal happens?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

The Data:

```
ACCOUNT       DESC   
Gallup        1 
Gallup        2
Phoenix       2
Red Rock      1
Red Rock      2 
Albuquerque   1
```

The desired output:

```
ACCOUNT       DESC   
Gallup        1,2
Phoenix       2
Red Rock      1,2
Albuquerque   1
```

but in a general scope as this is a small subset (Many other accounts, 100+)

Is there a way to remove duplicate values of "ACCOUNT" and to concatenate values from the removed duplicates where the "ACCOUNT" matched?? (this method is the preferred approach desired if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Right click Account column, Group By

use New Column name : **Data**, Operation: **All Rows**,

Add Column, Custom Column, formula

```
=Table.Column([Data],"DESC")
```

Click on arrows at top of new column, extract value, use comma delimiter

Remove extra column

Full sample code if data was in Table1:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ACCOUNT"}, {{"Data", each _, type table}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.Column([Data],"DESC")),
#"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Data"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: This method did work, but in instances it made longer concatenations like:
````
1,2
1,2
1,2,2,1,2,1,2
````

Comment: post an example of the data that came up with that result